# How to display an application window in all workspaces simultaneously (Gnome 42.9)

Tags: window-management, workspaces, window-title

In Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome) and earlier, one could show a given window in all workspaces simultaneously.
Can that be done in 22.04 (Gnome Shell 42.9).

If I have Gedit with configuration data as **App Z**, and I need to edit several parts of it for apps **A**, **B** and **C**; I could in 20.04 show **Z** in all workspaces, and **A** in *WS #1*, **B** in *#2*, **C** in *#3*.  Navigate to App **A**, check its part of the information held in **Z** - it's on the same workspace.  Then switch to workspace *#2* and look at **B**, do the same thing with the relevant part of **Z** which is next to it, etc.
Now apparently I have to either move **Z** around workspaces all the time, or have **A**,**B**,**C** and **Z**  somehow overlapping in the same workspace. This would involve lots of mouse movement rather than just keyboard actions. What am I missing?